# Why is my raster stack displaying all of the individual raster images instead of a merged raster image?

Tags: r, stack, raster

I am attempting to plot an image composed of a stack of raster images. Using reproducible data:

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package = "raster"))
b
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 77, 101, 7777, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent     : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=merc +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#source     : /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/raster/external/rlogo.grd 
#names      : red, green, blue 
#min values :   0,     0,    0 
#max values : 255,   255,  255 

library(rasterVis)
levelplot(b)
```

This produces a [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCfms.png) of the 3 raster layers side by side

What I want to do is plot it so that the image displays the "R" logo only once with the 'red', 'green' and 'blue' layers stacked on top of each other by using their mean values.

Can anyone please help achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question to make it *minimal, self-contained, and reproducible*. Thus, use some data that ships with R (e.g. `b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))`. Or create some with code. Do not refer to files that we do not have, and do not show processing not relevant to the question at hand.   It also not clear to me what you expect from plotting raster on the of one another (the last one would cover the  others?)

Comment: I have just reformatted the question so that it should be easily reproducible. Thank you, Robert!

Comment: Can you better explain how you want the three images combined? Do you want them to blend? Use their mean value? Treat them as RGB channels?  "stacked on top of each other" is not clear (if you really wanted that you could just plot the last one)

Comment: Okay, I see how my language choice could make that confusing. I'd like to use their mean value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the mean value of a RasterStack (or RasterBrick)

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package = "raster"))

bm <- mean(b)
plot(bm)
```